# Can I use Vine VNC server to share a USB port from a PC?

Tags: macos, vnc

Can I install a Vine VNC server on my Mac Mini and share a USB port on my Windows 7 laptop running Vine viewer? I would like to connect my iPhone to my Windows 7 laptop and configure the Vine server on my Mac Mini to be able to see it. The goal is to connect to the Mac Mini from the Windows 7 laptop via Vine viewer, create an iPhone app using XCode on the Mac Mini and install it on to the iPhone connected to the Windows 7 laptop.

Will Vine VNC server or any other VNC server allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

VNC doesn't let you do that - it's simply a way to transfer the contents of a screen from one system to another. Quite simply, it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: screen contents and input from devices like keyboards & mice.  the commercial RealVNC (enterprise edition) also does file transfer.  otherwise +1, correct.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve what I want to?

Comment: It might not be relevant to you now, but NoMachine supports redirecting USB devices connected in your Windows laptop to remote Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The [Eltima USB to Ethernet Connector](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) is the closest thing I've found so far, researching for a solution to the same situation. It also has a [Mac version](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-network-mac/).

I've got the exact same problem.  The Mac is a shared resource in my office, and I'm off-site most of the time.  The simulator is okay for most situations, but I'd really like to install the app on my phone without having to drive all the way in to the office every time.

Comment: FYI You have to "request a trial" for that software and full price is $150. Too ritzy for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using now is [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com)

Works great.  Using this site you can archive your app and deploy to your phone as an ad hoc deployment.  Of course this still doesn't solve the the issue if your intention is to debug code directly on the phone.  Though testflight does at least give you nice stack traces, logs your crashes, etc.  Not as good as stepping into a debug session, but it's something.

Comment: TestFlight was acquired by Apple in February 2014.

Comment: Yes, yes it was.